# How to Install Ruby-on-Rails in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

Now i m using Amazon EC2 for Ruby-on-Rails, After Login how can i Install Ruby-on-Rails.

Comment: I have been following this one https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help

A   Install RVM

```
$ sudo apt-get install git curl
```

2   Now we need to make sure we have some dependencies for our development environment so install the next few packages

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential automake libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev zlib1g subversion zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3  libc6-dev ncurses-dev libtool bison
```

3   Now it is time to install RVM which can be done easily with the next command.

```
$ bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

4   Set Rvm Home Directory

```
$ echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

5   load the edited bashrc file we run:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

6   Check The installed RVM ----> Output - rvm is a function

```
$ type rvm  | head -1
```

B   Install Ruby 1.9.2 /1.9.3 using rvm

1   $ rvm install 1.9.3

2   Check ruby status

```
$ ruby -v
```

3   Make Installed Ruby Version as default

```
$ rvm use --default 1.9.3
```

C   Install Rails

```
$ gem install rails
```

1   Check Rails Version

```
$ rails -v
```

D   Install Passenger with Nginx Module

1   Create Nginx Default Install Directory and provide same once asked by installer

```
$ mkdir /home/<user>/.nginx
```

1   Install the Phusion Passenger gem

```
$ gem install passenger
```

2   Run the Phusion Passenger installer for Nginx

```
$ passenger-install-nginx-module
```

3   Command to Start Passanger

1   Passenger start -p